# angular 2 how to change inner attribute of input property

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-directive, angular-components

i have create input property of slider 
 @Input('inputSlider') inputSlider: SliderComponent;
 and i wanna change only the imageurls array(attribute) in each different component
its possible?if yes,how should i do it

```js
import { AboutComponent } from './../about/about.component';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent  { 

  @Input('inputSlider') inputSlider: SliderComponent;

  height: string = '400px';
  minHeight: string;
  arrowSize: string = '30px';
  showArrows: boolean = false;
  disableSwiping: boolean = false;
  autoPlay: boolean = true;
  autoPlayInterval: number = 3333;
  stopAutoPlayOnSlide: boolean = true;
  debug: boolean = false;
  backgroundSize: string = 'cover';
  backgroundPosition: string = 'center center';
  backgroundRepeat: string = 'no-repeat';
  showDots: boolean = false;
  width: string = '100%';
  reloded: boolean = true;

  imageUrls = [
    'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56748793/dbohn_170625_1801_0018.0.0.jpg',
    'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/9278671/jbareham_170917_2000_0124.jpg',
    'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56789263/akrales_170919_1976_0104.0.jpg',
    'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56674755/mr_pb_is_the_best.0.jpg'
  ];
 

}
```

```html
<slideshow #slideshow [imageUrls]="imageUrls" [height]="height" [minHeight]="minHeight" [arrowSize]="arrowSize" [showArrows]="showArrows"
[disableSwiping]="disableSwiping" [autoPlay]="autoPlay" [stopAutoPlayOnSlide]="stopAutoPlayOnSlide" [debug]="debug" [backgroundSize]="backgroundSize"
[backgroundPosition]="backgroundPosition" [backgroundRepeat]="backgroundRepeat" [showDots]="showDots">
</slideshow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your question but there is some mismatching in your code like the component that you created is "app-slider" template and CSS that you are using "slider.component.*" and in the HTML code you are having 
So unable to get that completely.
But, yes whatever you want to do that is very simple input and output are the main features of such behavior.
If you can provide me proper your code and structure I can help you more. For the reference, you can check these links: 
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-input-and-output-example
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Thanks